# How can I update text of dynamic component on react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I´m new to react and react-native, I want to show a component that  is composed of:

[image: Schedule]

so when the user checks the corresponding checkbox I transform the mentioned component adding another view getting something like this:

[image]

The problem comes when the user clicks on the Text element because I show a modal to pick the desired hour and minutes and when this modal closes I'm pretending to update the state and this updates the Text element with the selected time but it´s not working, any advice?

this is my code:

```
 import React from 'react';
    import {View,Text, TextInput, StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
    import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';
    import DateTimePicker from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';

    let frmHoras; 

    export default class CustomChkHorario extends React.Component{

        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state={
                chk:false,
                fontColor:'black',
                title:'Closed',
                isDateTimePickerVisible: false,
                sTimeMonday:'00:00',
                eTimeMonday:'00:00'
            }
        }

        _showDateTimePicker = () => {
            this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: true });
        }

        _hideDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: false });

        _handleDatePicked = (date) => {
          console.log('A date has been picked: ', date);
          this.setState({sTimeMonday:date});
          this._hideDateTimePicker();
        };

        pressedChk = () => {
            //console.log('checked:',this.state.checked);
            this.setState({chk:!this.state.chk}, () =>{
                if(this.state.chk==false){
                    this.setState({fontColor:'black', title:'Closed'});
                    frmHoras=null;
                }else{
                    this.setState({fontColor:'green', title:'Open'});
                    frmHoras=
                        <View style={{flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'center'}}>
                            <Text>from:</Text> 
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._showDateTimePicker}>
                                <Text style={styles.input}>{this.state.sTimeMonday}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <Text>to:</Text>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._showDateTimePicker}>
                                <Text style={styles.input}></Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>;
                }
            });


        }

        render(){
            return(
                <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
                    <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                        <Text>{this.props.dia}</Text>
                        <CheckBox title={this.state.title}
                            checked={this.state.chk}
                            onPress={this.pressedChk}
                            checkedColor='green'
                            textStyle={{color:this.state.fontColor}}></CheckBox>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        {frmHoras}
                    </View>
                    <DateTimePicker
                        isVisible={this.state.isDateTimePickerVisible}
                        onConfirm={this._handleDatePicked}
                        onCancel={this._hideDateTimePicker}
                        mode={'time'}
                    />
                </View>
            );        
        }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        input: {
            marginHorizontal: 10,     
            height:25,
            width:60,
            borderBottomColor:'black',
            borderStyle:'solid',
            borderBottomWidth:1,
            margin:10
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  _handleDatePicked = date => {
    const time = new Date(date);
    const timePicked = `${time.getHours()}:${time.getMinutes()}`;

    this.setState({ sTimeMonday: timePicked });
    this._hideDateTimePicker();
  };

  pressedChk = () => {
    this.setState({ chk: !this.state.chk }, () => {
      if (this.state.chk) {
        this.setState({ fontColor: 'green', title: 'Open' });
      } else {
        this.setState({ fontColor: 'black', title: 'Closed' });
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <Text>{this.props.dia}</Text>
          <CheckBox
            title={this.state.title}
            checked={this.state.chk}
            onPress={this.pressedChk}
            checkedColor="green"
            textStyle={{ color: this.state.fontColor }}
          />
        </View>
        {this.state.chk && (
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text>from:</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._showDateTimePicker}>
              <Text style={styles.input}>{this.state.sTimeMonday}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>to:</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._showDateTimePicker}>
              <Text style={styles.input} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
        <DateTimePicker
          isVisible={this.state.isDateTimePickerVisible}
          onConfirm={this._handleDatePicked}
          onCancel={this._hideDateTimePicker}
          mode={'time'}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should render `frmHoras` in a function, but you are currently doing that in the `setState` callback, which is a bit misleading in your case, as `setState` callback is called when `setState` is completed and the component is re-rendered. Look at the [document](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) which clearly mentioned about this behaviour

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.

So, changes will as follows

Create a new function which will render `frmHoras`, let it be `renderFrmHoras`

```
renderFrmHoras = () => {
  const { chk } = this.state;
  if(!chk) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'center'}}>
     <Text>from:</Text> 
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._showDateTimePicker}>
       <Text style={styles.input}>{this.state.sTimeMonday}</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
     <Text>to:</Text>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._showDateTimePicker}>
       <Text style={styles.input}></Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>;
  );
}
```

Next, update the `pressedChk` to set `fontColor`, `title` and `chk` values

```
pressedChk = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return ({
      chk: !prevState.chk,
      fontColor: !prevState.chk ? 'green' : 'black',
      title: !prevState.chk ? 'Open' : 'Closed'
    });
  })
}
```

Next, in the render method, just call the `renderFrmHoras` function

```
render() {
  return (
    ...
    </View>
    <View>
       {this.renderFrmHoras()}
    </View>
    <DateTimePicker
     ...
    />
    ...
  );
}
```

Hope this will help!